# Infinite redirect caused by a script

Tags: javascript

guys I would like to know if you see anything on this code that would cause infinite redirect. I just can't figure it out. This is using GeoIP2 API, which is loading correctly.

```
var redirect = (function () {
  var onSuccess = function (geoipResponse) {
    var sites = {
      "cn": true
    };

    if (!geoipResponse.country.iso_code) {
        window.location.replace("http://gotriplec.com/");
    }

    var code = geoipResponse.country.iso_code.toLowerCase();

    if (sites[code]) {
      alert("Your IP cannot access this website... We apologize for any inconvenience caused.");
      window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
    }

    else {
      window.location.replace("http://gotriplec.com/");
    }
  };

  var onError = function (error) {
    window.location.replace("http://gotriplec.com/");
  };

  return function () {
    geoip2.country( onSuccess, onError );
  };
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without looking at other parts of code, cannot tell much, but if your site is "http://gotriplec.com/" and you call `redirect()` on page load/  ready on this page, that scenario would cause an infinite redirect.

Comment: Ahhh I see the issue by reading your message. I have window.location.replace on each login. If i only leave it for the proper redirect, it should work....